# How to add properties to initially typed object

Tags: typescript

The example below uses quite simple object structures (it's slightly simplified for the purpose of the question). The logic uses cloning to avoid mutating original configuration object.

I am new to TS and a bit puzzled to understand how to preserve typesafe way of coding, in order to modify object and return it typed with another type.

I will also appreciate your thought on this approach in TS and will be glad to learn about a better one :)

[Here is an example of working code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-mountain-4qhjr)

```
function cloneDeep<T>(object: T): T {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object)) as T;
}

type initialConfigType = {
  a: {
    b: number
  }
  c: number
};

interface extendedConfigType extends initialConfigType {
  d: number
}

const initalConfig: initialConfigType = {
  a: {
    b: 1
  },
  c: 1
};

function extendConfig(config: initialConfigType) {
  const configClone = cloneDeep(config)

  // Property 'd' does not exist on type 'initialConfigType' 
  configClone.d = 3

  return configClone as extendedConfigType
}

const extendedConfig = extendConfig(initalConfig)
```

Comment: you can move type assertion to the first line `const configClone = cloneDeep(config) as extendedConfigType`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe don't change the original config:

```
function extendConfig(config: initialConfigType) {
  return {
    ...cloneDeep(config),
    d: 3
  }
}
```

Comment: Original config is not changed anyway (there's a clone for this)

Comment: I meant the cloned one. Much more natural to create a new object than modify the existing ones in Typescript.

Comment: Unnecessarily created object ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Who can afford so much memory? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  If only garbage collectors existed. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  Also you escaped the right hand. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Functional programming languages do that literally all the time and for really good reasons.

Comment: It actually can be useful if you'll add return type for the function `function extendConfig(config: initialConfigType): extendedConfigType ...` so it will require to fill extra props

Answer (score 0):

For deep cloning I recommend to use lodash library, which already implements a clonedeep func.

```
const clonedeep = require('lodash.clonedeep');
```

To stick to your way this should work. With no lint errors

```
function cloneDeep<T>(object: T): T {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object)) as T;
}

type initialConfigType = {
    a: {
        b: number
    }
    c: number
};

interface extendedConfigType extends initialConfigType {
    d: number
}

const initalConfig: initialConfigType = {
    a: {
        b: 1
    },
    c: 1
};

function extendConfig(config: initialConfigType): extendedConfigType {
    let configClone: extendedConfigType;
    configClone = { ...configClone, ...{ config } }
    configClone.d = 3

    return configClone;
}

const extendedConfig = extendConfig(cloneDeep(initalConfig))

initalConfig.a.b = 9;

console.log(initalConfig, extendedConfig);
```